# Creating an anagram checker

Tags: python, function, if-statement, conditional-statements, anagram

So I have been able to create the following program which compares two strings to see if they are anagrams of each other.

```
def anagrams( string1, string2 ):
    if sorted(string1.lower()) == sorted(string2.lower()):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

However, my issue is that I wish to not return a True value should both input strings be the exact same. For example:

```
anagrams('silent','silent')
```

This outputs True but I do not want it to do that, what changes should I make to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check if the strings are different:

```
def anagrams(string1, string2):
    if sorted(string1.lower()) == sorted(string2.lower()) and string1.lower() != string2.lower():
        return True
    else:
        return False

result = anagrams('silent', 'silent')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
False
```

You could use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of sorted:

```
from collections import Counter


def anagrams(string1, string2):
    if string1.lower() != string2.lower() and Counter(string1.lower()) == Counter(string2.lower()):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(anagrams('silent', 'silent'))
print(anagrams('silent', 'sitlen'))
```

**Output**

```
False
True
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @RoadRunner, you could do:

```
from collections import Counter


def anagrams(string1, string2):
    ls1, ls2 = string1.lower(), string2.lower()
    return ls1 != ls2 and Counter(ls1) == Counter(ls2)

print(anagrams('silent', 'silent'))
print(anagrams('silent', 'sitlen'))
```

Comment: i have never used counter before, what does that do?

Comment: It creates a dictionary where the keys are the elements and the values are the frequencies.

Comment: +1 for brief and helpful answer but I think you should check for `string1.lower() != string2.lower()` since "silent" and "Silent" shouldn't really pass

Comment: @frustration give credit where it is due and accept this answer.

Comment: You could also just `return string1 != string2 and Counter(string1) == Counter(string2)`. No need for if/else.

Comment: @Ayxan sorry i'm fairly new to this i hadn't realised that was a thing aside from my comment reply of acknowledgement, done now

Answer (score 0):

```
def anagrams( string1, string2 ):
  if sorted(string1.lower()) == sorted(string2.lower()) and string1.lower() != string2.lower():
    return True
  else:
    return False

print(anagrams('silent','silent'))
```